My MacBook stopped charging after I reset the SMC
I have MacBook Pro late 2011. I decided to reset the SMC controller with the charger connected (not original, cheap). When I did the SMC reset, the MagSafe indication did not change. When I turned on the MacBook, the fans were running at full power, but MagSafe was burning red. Then I turned off the MacBook, turned off the charging and plugged it back in, but the charging indicator was no longer on MagSafe. The battery is not charging.
What do I do in this situation?

The problem was solved by itself after the MacBook had been lying in a hot car for two whole days. When I took the MacBook out of the car, it was so hot that it hurt to even touch it. I let it cool down, and when I pressed the battery indicator, it was working properly. After that, when I connected the same Chinese charger, the charging started and the MacBook turned on itself. I didn't see any problems after that.
